# Declaration in for gives segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm doing a homework for learning graphs. For that, I'm taking a csv file and I keep that information in a Sensor structure.

```c
#define sensor_amount 70
typedef struct Sensor {
    int id;
    float x,y,z;
}Sensor;
```

For getting this struct from file I'm using the following function:

```c
Sensor* get_sensors(char* file_name){
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name,"r");
    //Skip first line
    char* c;
    fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",c);

    int id = 0;
    float x,y,z;

    Sensor* sensor_arr = malloc(sizeof(Sensor));
    fscanf(file,"%i,%f,%f,%f",&id,&x,&y,&z);
    sensor_arr[0].id = id;
    sensor_arr[0].x = x;
    sensor_arr[0].y = y;
    sensor_arr[0].z = z;

    int counter = 1;

    while(!feof(file)){
        fscanf(file,"%i,%f,%f,%f\n",&id,&x,&y,&z);
        ++counter;
        sensor_arr = realloc(sensor_arr,counter*sizeof(Sensor));
        sensor_arr[counter-1].id = id;
        sensor_arr[counter-1].x = x;
        sensor_arr[counter-1].y = y;
        sensor_arr[counter-1].z = z; 
    }
    fclose(file);
    return sensor_arr;
}
```

I'm calculating distances between each sensor with following code:

```c
float** get_distances(Sensor* s){
    float** a = malloc(sensor_amount*sizeof(float*));

    for(int i = 0; i < sensor_amount;i++)
        a[i] = malloc(sensor_amount*sizeof(float));

    for(int i = 0; i < sensor_amount;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < sensor_amount; j++){
            float dis = distance(s[i].x,s[i].y,s[j].x,s[j].y);
            a[i][j] = dis;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Finally in my main i print those values like this:

```c
int i,j;
int main(){
    char file_name[] = "sensor_locations.csv";
    Sensor* sensors; 
    sensors = get_sensors(file_name);
    float**ar=get_distances(sensors);
    for(i=0;i < 70; ++i)
        for(j=0;j<70;++j){
            printf("(%i,%i)->%f\n",i,j,ar[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In main, if I move the declarations of i and j to the for loops, it throws a segmentation fault. But why?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and not code snippets that must be stiched together. Also learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: `char* c;
    fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",c);` is invalid, you are using unintialized pointer `c` to store the first line of input. You should add error checking to your code. Each `malloc` can fail, each `fscanf` can fail, a `fopen` can fail - you just ignore errors.

Comment: Another probable cause: your indexes might be out of range, add some code that checks that.

Comment: The hard-wired occurrences of 70 are red flags.  How does what know the size of anything?  It isn’t obvious how anything works. But the symptoms (the crash) point to undefined behaviour.

Comment: please describe, what the `distance` function does in this statement? `float dis = distance(s[i].x,s[i].y,s[j].x,s[j].y);`

Answer (score 0):

This is designed for array out of bounds bugs:

```
int counter = 1;
...
++counter;
...
[counter-1]
```

Instead do

```
for(int i=0; more_data; i++)
{
  sensor_arr[i] = ...;
  sensor_arr = realloc(sensor_arr,(i+2)*sizeof(Sensor));
}
```

Please note [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

And your use of `realloc` is wrong, use a tmp pointer for storing the result and check it against NULL before assigning it back to the `sensor_arr` pointer.

Comment: It appears that the problem really was my usage of feof(file). I writed a function for count lines in the file and in that function I used the return value of fgets. Thank you very much.